# MS Teams Approvals 'Upload failed File size too large"

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams, o365-flow

I am using a teams "Approvals" App for eSignature and Approvals of documents. When I try to attach files over 10MB, I am getting 'Upload failed File size too large" error message.
We are on 365 and it happens to all users. I tried with admin credentials still the same error
I can attach the larger files to email and send with no issues
Attachment size for outlook is set to 36MB
On powerplatform admin center the attachments is set to as 36MB for the organization
I am not sure where else to set the limit.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was using Adobe eSign feature, and the file size limit for Adobe is 10MB.